What is the cause of magnetization?
the relation between magnetic field strength and magnetic influx is: $H=B/\mu-M$.
M is called magnetization. In case of magnetic bar, it exists only inside the bar.
The relation is shown in this illustration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:VFPt_magnets_BHM.svg
It's said that the B field is caused by the bond current of the magnetic bar. May I ask what is the cause of this magnetization and why it has bigger magnitude then the H field that excite it and pointing from south to north? and how can a field be confined within a limited shaped space (not exist outside of the magnetic bar)?
Another question is why the relationship is a subtraction instead of addition of a quantity with opposite direction which as I know how all formula in physics is based on?

Most books written in the last 100 years would say that $B$ is the true or real physical field an $H$ is secondary and derived from $B$, while before and during the development of EM reverse view was prevalent that $H$ be the primary; engineers still prefer to start with  $H$ for very practical reasons.
Since in a vacuum the two fields, $H$ and $B=\mu_0 H$ are the same except for a dimensional coefficient $\mu_0$ whose value is determined by convention it makes no sense to assign meaning to the question of which quantity is more fundamental. In a macroscopic magnetic material the situation is different. The two fields have different behaviors across boundaries: specifically, $B_n$ is always continuous while $\Delta H_t=J_t$ representing the tangential jump in the $H$ field equals the surface current flowing between the two media; if $J_t=0$, no surface current, then $\Delta H_t=0$, in other words, $H_t$ is continuous across the boundary.
Because of these differences their measurements are different inside magnetic matter. We usually associate force with $H$ and torque with $B$ but to measure these you need an empty cavity within the magnetic body. Due to the boundary condition differences one employs different shaped cavities, Kelvin's crevices. To measure the force a long and narrow needle-shaped cavity that is parallel with the local $H$ field inside the body will do because in the needle cavity and just outside of it but still within the magnetic body the two the $H$ fields will be equal. Contrariwise, a disk-shaped flat and thin cavity perpendicular to the local $B$ field will have the same $B$ field inside as it is immediately outside. These differences can be shown to be captured by the introduction of the magnetic polarization density field denoted by $M$, so that $B=\mu_0(H+M)$. It is completely without physical significance with what sign you define this $M$, one could just as well have defined it as $B=\mu_0 (H-M).$
There are two "causes" for a magnetic field in classical EM, one cause is a moving charge, a current, and the other possible cause is an irreducible magnetic dipole as the source. Neither can be explained any more than the cause for inertia in Newtonian mechanics. It just is. Since a circular current has the same magnetic field at distances large relative to its diameter it can be assigned a magnetic dipole moment similar to that of the irreducible magnetic moments, the macroscopic averages of fields of particles and atomic/electronic currents can be represented by $M$. Note that the relationship among these three macroscopic fields $f(B,H,M)=0$ is no more accessible to classical analysis than, say, the ideal gas law $pV=nRT$ or Hooke's law $F=-kx$. These are macroscopic constitutive "laws" defining the body under examination. Their explanation is outside of EM, mechanics, and thermodynamics; they are assumed subjects of investigation but not explained. Their explanation is in statistical mechanics, solid-state physics, quantum mechanics, etc.

There are examples in other fields of science where two quantities are different but intertwined -- stress and strain are a good example.  Voltage and current.  Pressure and flow rate.  These are easier to conceptualize than B, H, and M.  But the idea that  there are mutually related fields of different natures isn't unique to magnetism.

If you have already been introduced to vector analysis concepts then this answer may also help to understand better the relationship among these vectors $M,H,B$ https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/452315/the-form-of-h-in-a-bar-magnet

In addition to hyportnex's excellent answer, I would like to add something regarding the cause of macroscopic magnetisation.
According to the Bohr-Van Leeuwen theorem, the thermal average of magnetisation is always zero if classical mechanics and statistical mechanics are assumed. This means macroscopic magnetism as we know it is purely quantum mechanical in nature.
Wikipedia gives a good summary:

The origin of the magnetic moments responsible for magnetization can be either microscopic electric currents resulting from the motion of electrons in atoms, or the spin of the electrons or the nuclei.

These phenomena give rise to a vibrant list of magnetic behaviours, such as ferromagnetism, paramagnetism, etc.; in the specific example of a bar magnet you mentioned, ferromagnetism is the most important factor in determining the magnetisation.
